# Ugly navigation bar in fullscreen mode on firefox mobile after input

Tags: android, firefox, progressive-web-apps, html5-fullscreen

I get an ugly navigation bar in fullscreen mode on firefox mobile after input. Steps to reproduce:

1. Open website in Firefox on Android: https://app.usecue.com
2. Add to homescreen to go to full screen mode (or trigger it in another way): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl3wo.png
3. Get the virtual keyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7vlf.png
4. Hide the virtual keyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVom6.png

You see that the soft navigation buttons from Android are still on my screen. They do not disappear and make my PWA non-functional.

Is this a bug or just bad programming? Note that Chrome hides them after a few seconds and makes them semi-transparent, which makes me believe this is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also having this issue, but it looks like it is solved in Firefox Nightly as of 11/9/2020. I hate waiting on bugs from Mobile Firefox but I hope this helps!